# SharePoint 2013 Top Nav Flyout Not Working

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, quick-launch, global-navigation, top-navigation

I have a custom designed HTML master page.  Now that I've styled everything the way I want, I am unable to get the fly out menu to work on the Global Navigation.  I have updated the Snippet to include changing the MaxiumDynamicDisplayLevels to 2 and StaticDisplayLevels to 1.  However, none of these changes are reflected in the masterpage when I update it.  I noticed there is a div wrapped around the enter ASPMenu with this dataname `<div data-name="TopNavigationNoFlyoutWithStartNode">`.  So my assumption is that this probably has something to do with it - how do I activate the flyout menu?  To note, I am not using Managed Metadata as I don't have access to Central Admin.

Also, strangely enough, if I paste the new Snippet code into my masterpage, it interferes with a script I have implemented to make my QuickLaunch an accordion menu.  All of the links are then expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue.  For whatever reason, SharePoint CSS had a visibility set to hidden attribute in the CSS for the submenu.  Overriding that corrected the issue for me.